# My dev++ is returning non-static warning. Whats the problem with the code?

Tags: c, struct

I'm doing this code and can't find a way to compile. Tried Online compilers which each one of them gives a different reason for the error, my Dev++ says that
[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Every online compiler and cant find an error on code either

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct uninter
{
    char nome[5] = {'L','U','C','A','S'};
    int RU = 2613496;
}; struct uninter aluno;

int main() {
int i;

    printf("\n Nome do Aluno: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){

            printf( "%c\n", aluno.nome[i]);
        }
    printf("\n RU do aluno: %d \n ", aluno.RU);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: Seems you are using a C++ compiler rather than a C compiler based on that warning message.

Comment: Is dev++ only a C++ compiler? geez my teacher was using on the class..

Comment: I don't have experience with `dev++`, so I can't say if does C, but it's definitely currently being used for C++.  For the record, this code would not be valid C code since you cannot create a default initializer for C structs.

Comment: @LucasAnderson No Dev++ is only the IDE, it probably uses MinGW/GCC on windows, which can compile C or C++. I can't tell you about dev++ specifically, but usually there is a setting for the compilation language or it is determined by the file ending which language is compiled (e.g. `.c` for C, `.cpp` for C++). Please clear up which language you intend to use and verify that your IDE is set up correctly to compile in that language.

Comment: I'm trying to do a C code. but my teacher said to make a structure and store these letters. Didn't know it was a limitation of the compiler. I'm really a begginer and don't know what to do.

Comment: @LucasAnderson as answered below C doesn't allow initializing members in the structure definition. It is not a limitation of the compiler, it is simply not correct in C. (It is different for C++). I hope you teacher didn't tell you to write `= ...` in a `struct` definition. It is not possible in C. Having a `char[5]` as `struct` member is fine though, again see answers below.

Answer (score 2):

The warning message you are receiving is because you are compiling your code with a C++ compiler.  Probably with with `-std=c++98` or `-ansi` or otherwise implicitly using the 1998 standard.

You are trying to create a default initializer for a member of a struct, which is a feature not added to C++ until the 2011 standard.  To compile a C++ program with this feature without the compiler warning you about this, you need to pass in the `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` flags to the compiler command as the warning states.

If this is expected to be C code rather than C++ code, default initializers for structs are simply not a part of the language.  You can initialize its member variables upon declaration of an object of that struct's type.

An example of how you might do this with a C compiler:

```
// definition of the struct
struct uninter
{
    char nome[5];
    int RU;
};

// declaration of an instance of an object of type struct uninter
struct uninter x = {{'L','U','C','A','S'}, 2613496};

// alternative declaration if using C99 standard with designated initializers
struct uninter y = {
    .nome={'L','U','C','A','S'},
    .RU= 2613496
};
```

Comment: An additional note for OP: As long as you are (unintentionally) compiling your code as C++ instead of C, the last example code shown wont compile (because it is valid C, but not valid C++, at least not until C++20). Really make sure you are compiling as C, first.

Answer (score 0):

in general, cannot initialize a struct contents in C in the definition of the struct.  Suggest something similar to:

```
struct uninter
{
    char nome[5];
    int RU;
}; 

struct uninter aluno = {.nome = "LUCAS", .RU = 2613496};
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the code is that it is using non-static data member intializers:

```
struct uninter
{
    char nome[5] = {'L','U','C','A','S'};
    int RU = 2613496;
}; struct uninter aluno;
```

... which is a C++11 feature, and therefore isn't portable unless you are using a C++11 (or later) compiler.  (It might still compile under older compilers, if they have that feature enabled as a compiler-specific extension, but they are politely warning you that you can't expect it to compile everywhere)

If you don't want your program to require C++11 or later to compile, the easiest thing to do would be to rewrite it so that the struct's member variables are initialized via a different mechanism.  For example (assuming your `c` tag is intentional) you could have an init-method do it for you:

```
struct uninter
{
    char nome[5+1];   // +1 for the NUL/terminator byte!
    int RU;
}; struct uninter aluno;

void Init_uninter(uninter * u)
{
   strcpy(u->nome, "LUCAS");
   u->RU = 2613496;
}

[...]

int main() {
int i;

Init_uninter(&aluno);
[...]
```

... or if you actually intended to specify/use a pre-C++11 version of C++, a default-constructor would do the trick a bit more gracefully:

```
struct uninter
{
   uninter()
   {
      strcpy(nome, "LUCAS");
      RU = 2613496;
   }

   char nome[5+1];   // +1 for the NUL terminator byte!
   int RU;
}; struct uninter aluno;
```

Comment: It's a good solution thanks. But i don't know how to explain that to him, because we didn't learn what is "Init" yet. We just learned about Struct and he wanted me to do an array with these letters and numbers on a struct.

Comment: There's nothing special about "Init_uninter", that's just the name I chose for my function that sets the values in the struct.  You could name the function whatever you wanted to name it, it would work the same.